# rsyncing /home between 10.04 and 11.04

Tags: rsync, home-directory

My co-worker has an old laptop with Ubuntu **10.04** installed on it. About a week ago I backed up her /home directory using rsync, and kept it on an external HD.
Now, she got a new laptop with Ubuntu **11.04**.

I am still pretty new to the Ubuntu file system, so my question is this: Can I just rsync an Ubuntu 10.04 /home backup onto an Ubuntu 11.04 machine? Are there any directories I should not copy from the backup?

Answer (score 6):

There are a great many differences between how Gnome is configured in 10.04 and how it's configured in 11.04. While you might loose some settings from the 10.04 desktop I would strongly recommend leaving the `.gconf`, `.gnome`, `.gnome2`, `.gnome2_private`, `.gconf`, `.gconfd`, `.config`, and `.conf` folders behind. Moving these over from 10.04 to 11.04 have a high potential for corrupting the desktop. I would also recommend making a tar'd backup of the `/home` folder prior to any moves.

Comment: there are changes to the `.conf` folder as well. I would suggest to leave that one out as well. The new desktop has `.conf/dconf/user` which is generated by dconf tools which was not present in 10.04. PS: These above mentioned folders are hidden folders and you can view them by pressing `Ctrl + H` .

Answer (score -2):

Since you've used rsync you should have an exact copy of your friend's dir on your machine. There should not be any problems with copying between any other machines now.

The only to take care of is file owner.

Comment: @MarcinCycle Thanks! but are there no differences between the versions? 10.04 and 11.04

Comment: there may be differences as to version of rsync, but this should not influence the data you are sending, so you should not worry about that.

Comment: You *should* worry about it.