# How do I use gnome trash for files in different partition?

Tags: gnome, filesystem, trash

I have my files in a separate partition that is not mounted to `/home`, but only linked to it. How do I manage to be able to use the gnome trash in those files?

For example:

partion 2: mounted on `/data`, with a folder `/data/myname`

partion 1: mounted on `/`, with its own `/home` and `/home/myname`, inside it `/home/myname/Desktop` and `/home/myname/Documents` link to `/data/myname/Desktop` and `/data/myname/Document` respectively. Suppose I have a file `/data/myname/Document/example.txt`.

When I use nautilus, and try to delete `/home/myname/Document/example.txt`, Nautilus say it can't use the trash. It took me a while to figure out it is because `example.txt` is in a different filesystem. I don't know can another trash directory be defined in that partition so that gnome can use it?

I could have partion 2 mounted as `/home` with almost simular results --I did that for a long time--, but each time I change the Linux/Ubuntu installation, many configuration files in my home become broken. But in summary this new scheme doesn't allow me to use gnome trash now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GNOMEish file managers need a place to put the trashed files.  Copying them to the 1st partition would be very bad performance.  So it tries to put them in the /.Trash-$UID folder.  Without rw access to that folder, no trash.

Run this bash in the partition root as the user who needs a trash.

```
sudo mkdir .Trash-$UID && sudo chown $USER:$USER .Trash-$UID
```

Note:  If there is a a rw `.Trash` folder, Nautilus may create the user's trash folder automatically (`/.Trash/$UID`).  I haven't tried this, just saw it in some logs.  There are security issues with public trashes. YMMV.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, do below:

 `cd <mount-point-of-new-partition> && sudo chown root.root .Trash && sudo chmod ug-s .Trash && sudo chmod 1777 .Trash`

Comment: My method described above is not working with Ubuntu 21.04. Use the method that @Michael says

Answer (score 12):

When you delete a file on a removable storage device, GNOME automatically creates a trash folder at the device's root. If your user ID is 1000, it will create a file named /data/.Trash-1000. When you go to the Trash place in Nautilus, you see an amalgamation of all the trash folders for your user on all the filesystems that are connected.

It sounds like this one is a permissions issue. GNOME is trying to create the trash folder at the device's root, but perhaps your user only has access to individual files *under* the root. The easiest way about this is to make the thing more accessible. In a terminal, try `sudo chmod 777 /data` to make the root of your data drive editable to any user. Alternatively, you can do `sudo chown yourname /data` for a similar effect.

Comment: on the spot! As you said, just needed to do 'cd /data; chmod o+w .', (I guess it will also work to manually create /data/.Trash-1000 with the right permissions). Worked right away. (jeje, now I couldn't find the Trash in 11.10! ok, it is on the left panel in Nautilus)

Comment: I have my SSD mounted as / and some of the folders in my user /home mount (on a mechanical hard drive) are symlinked onto the SSD drive. While your fix (I created a .Trash-1000 off of /) allows me to use the move to trash option, I can't see the files I've deleted inside the Gnome trash in Nautilus. Any suggestions?

Comment: For security reasons, I'd suggest to created the .Trash-XXXX folder manually and give it the right permissions (755 or 750) for userid XXXX, instead of using 777 for the root directory of the other partition.

Comment: @James: you have to create the .Trash-XXXX folder in the root directory of the mounter partition, e.g. /mnt/data, not in /.