# No trash files in Trash or .Trash-$UID after deleting

Tags: partitioning, permissions, nautilus, delete, trash

When I delete files they do not end up in the Trash, `~/.local/share/Trash` or the Trash-$UID folder (partition). The folder exists, but the `expunged`, `files` and `info` folder in them are always empty. I have tried the `chmod chown` steps from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69517/how-do-i-use-gnome-trash-for-files-in-different-partition) but it didn't change anything. I have also checked the settings under Privacy -> File History & Trash and no automatic deletion is enabled.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Do you get any error message indicating a file you are trying to delete cannot move to trash but can be permanently deleted? Can you prove your theory about opening previous versions of files by creating and deleting text files just containing “version 1”, “version 2” etc...

Comment: I have changed the question because I wasn't able to reproduce the previous assumption and included the primary partition too in this problem. There are no error messages popping up.

Comment: How did you trash the files? using the command line `rm` or the GUI? `rm` will delete the files without sending to the trash.

Comment: using the GUI. Selected the file and pressed the `del` key on the keyboard