# How to install Xubuntu alongside Ubuntu Mate

Tags: usb, xubuntu, live-cd, mate, ubuntu-mate

I love both of these distros and I want them both. But I have no idea how you would do that. I bought a Ubuntu Mate cd which I used to install Mate but I also have a usb stick and I want to use that to install Xubuntu. How would I do that?

Comment: during installation, choose "install Xubuntu alongside Ubuntu MATE" (before you start, backup your backups)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Obtain an [image for Xubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)
2. [Verify the hash is correct](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso)
3. Apply the image to a media that you can boot from ([Optical](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672865/installing-ubuntu-burning-iso-file-onto-dvd) or
       [Flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal))
4. Boot from the live media - Choose Try Xubuntu
5. Select Install Xubuntu
6. When prompted, do as Zanna suggested in her comment and Choose the "Install Alongside" option.

Note: **This approach will work with any flavor of Ubuntu - Simply substitute the flavour of your choice for Xubuntu**.

Another option would be to add the [XFCE dekstop environment](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xubuntu-desktop) to your current installation and choose desktop environments at login rather than [dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207731/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-and-linux-mint-13?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 3):

Installing two Ubuntu flavors is one solution but it will double disk space usage, update procedures etc.

Alternatively you can open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` on your current installation and then just select the desktop environment you like, when your system starts.  This will not install system core files twice and both DE's will get updates at the same time.