# How to Install a Ubuntu DE without a current DE

Tags: desktop-environments, ubuntu-minimal

I wanted to install xfce on my ubuntu minimal virtual machine I installed ubuntu minimal without a desktop and I have installed xfce4 but how do I enable it without using the login page. Any answers would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you *have* installed a DE - but not a DM (*display manager*). Are you able to start the XFCE4 desktop after logging in, using the `startxfce4` command?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @steeldriver I ran the command and it didnt work the first time cause i was not in root.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to run `startxfce4` as root - in fact it's strongly discouraged to do so. What happens when you try to run it as your regular user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Xubuntu alongside Ubuntu Mate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823390/how-to-install-xubuntu-alongside-ubuntu-mate) - use `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`