# Sharing home partition across multiple Ubuntu OSes?

Tags: 13.10

I currently have Ubuntu 13.10 installed with a separate root and home partition on my drive. I want to install Elementary OS Luna as well. Would it be okay if I had the two operating systems share the same home partition as long as I use different usernames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in fact. But before that go through [this answer described use of common home partition for multiple linux distributions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55224/a-common-home-partition-for-multiple-linux-distributions).

If you wish you can use same [swap also for multiple linux distributions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/are-there-any-side-effects-when-two-distros-share-a-swap-partition).

Hope it would help.

Comment: I installed using the same home partition with different usernames and it worked perfectly. Thank you.