# dual boot whit Ubuntu and fedora

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, fedora

I have decided to install fedora 21 and Ubuntu 14.04 along side. Here I have two question:

1) how should I partition my disk so I can reinstall or change each distro without affecting other one?

2)can I access one ditros package from another distro?

Thakns

Answer (score 1):

1. You can partition it in various ways:

   - Atleast 30% of the disk for a root partition (containing /boot and other stuff), the rest for each OSs home partition (you can [share home partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55224/a-common-home-partition-for-multiple-linux-distributions) and some swap (for a suggestion for the size of the swap, you can try [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqoEj.png))
   - Similar to the above but a extra partition which is shared
   - Half the disk for each OS's root partition - no swap means you can't hibernate and if your RAM is too small you will run out of memory.

The possibilities are endless... If you want to change things after installation you can use GParted and edit `/etc/fstab` (carefully!)

2. Probably not possible, as Fedora uses much newer base packages and stuff than Ubuntu, also Fedora uses RPM packages to install stuff whilst Ubuntu uses DEB files. Copying other some things might work, but not always.